# small ball rotation animation inside the bigger ball

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I want to rotate the ball inside the circle so it touches every corner of the bigger circle and animation continuous infinitely as it is a logo animation.

```css
body {
  background-color: #272727;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.circle {
  width: 82px;
  height: 82px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  top: 18px;
  animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

I implemented the code but im confused how to rotate the smaller ball through transform-origin property so that its rotate inside the bigger circle and does not come out of the bigger circle.

Comment: `"so it touches every corner of the bigger circle"` - circles don't have corners so this is confusing

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - are you thinking in the right number of dimensions ... :D

Comment: u see the ball rotation i just want the black rotation inside the white ball not to come out of the white ball

Comment: @JaromandaX - more than likely not!

Comment: for some extent i have done i removed the top and left position spacing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just remove this CSS code line `animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;` from the `.circle` class and add to the `.line` class in your CSS code. You will achieve the animation that you want.

```css
body {
  background-color: #272727;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
}

.circle {
  width: 82px;
  height: 82px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  top: 18px;
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need all that code. Here is a simple version:

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px; /* control the size of the white circle */
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(50% 50%,#000 99%,#0000 101%) no-repeat
    top/80% 80% /* adjust the 80% to control the size of the black circle*/
    #fff;
  animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    rotate: 1turn;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #272727;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```